# Does Joyce Meyer preach salvation by faith in Jesus alone (ie not works)?

Tags: soteriology

A non-Christian colleague is really interested in [Joyce Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyce_Meyer) and is watching a lot of her talks. I don't know much about her (I only saw one talk and it was soundly Biblical).

Does she preach the basic Christian message of salvation by faith in Jesus alone, as described in [John 14:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+14%3A6&version=AMP)

> Jesus said to him, I am the Way and the Truth and the Life; no one comes to the Father except by (through) Me.

and [Ephesians 2:8-9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians+2%3A8-9&version=AMP)?

> For it is by free grace (God’s unmerited favor) that you are saved ([a]delivered from judgment and made partakers of Christ’s salvation) through [your] faith. And this [salvation] is not of yourselves [of your own doing, it came not through your own striving], but it is the gift of God;
>
> Not because of works [not the fulfillment of the Law’s demands], lest any man should boast. [It is not the result of what anyone can possibly do, so no one can pride himself in it or take glory to himself.]

<sub>Quoting from the [Amplified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplified_Bible) version which seems to be her preference, also.</sub>

Comment: [Related question on Joyce Meyer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/38876/30).

Comment: So, [is this an objectively answerable question, or is it primarily-opinion based](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6543/30)?

Comment: "Salvation by faith in Jesus alone (ie not works)" is not "the basic Christian message." Anything that nearly two-thirds of Christianity rejects cannot be called "the basic Christian message." It is, rather, the basic *Protestant* message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

From [the statement of Faith](http://www.joycemeyer.org/AboutUs/WhatWeBelieve.aspx) on [her website](http://www.joycemeyer.org/), regarding salvation:

> Man is created in the image of God but separated from God by sin. Without Jesus we cannot have a relationship with God. (references: Genesis 1:26; 1 Timothy 2:5) We can have a personal relationship with God through salvation, God's free gift to man. It is not a result of what we do, but it is only available through God's unearned favor. By admitting we have sinned and believing in the death, burial and resurrection of Christ, and accepting Him as Lord, we can spend eternity with God. (references: 
>   Ephesians 2:8,9; Romans 5:1; Romans 3:24)

Some relevant quotes from [Battlefield of the Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446691097) (one of her more popular books):

> I know I don't deserve God's blessings, but I receive them anyway because I am a joint-heir with Christ (Rom. 8:17 KJV). He earned them, and I get them by placing my faith in Him -p297

and

> [after quoting Hebrews 11:6] Please notice that without faith you cannot please God; therefore, no matter how many "good works" you offer, it will not please Him if they are done to "earn" His favor. Whatever we do for God should be because we love Him, not because we are trying to get something from Him. -p300

Although it may not be her most widely read material, most directly relevant to your question, would be the gospel presentation booklet she has produced - [The Most Important Decision You Will Ever Make](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446691534). This is not a theological statement on soteriology, but a practical guide to one seeking salvation. It is quite a detailed presentation but towards the end of the 4th chapter (entitled "What Should You Believe") the following Summary is given:

> To be born again you must believe:
>
> • God is. (Gen. 1:1; Heb. 11:6.)
>
> • Jesus is the Son of God, born of a virgin, 
>   born of flesh and blood. (Matt. 1:18; Matt. 
>   1:23.)
>
> • Jesus is God, one part of the Trinity, one 
>   part of the Triune Godhead. (Col. 2:9,10; Heb. 1:5-8.)
>
> • He came in a fleshly body so He could help 
>   man. (John 1:1; John 1:14; Luke 4:18-21.)
>
> • He took on Himself all your sins, bore them 
>   in His own body on the cross. (Isa. 53:4,5; 2 
>   Cor. 5:21.)
>
> • He died for your sins. (Heb. 2:9)
>
> • He went to hell in your place and gained 
>   victory there, triumphing over the enemy. 
>   (Acts 2:31)
>
> • On the third day, He arose again from the 
>   dead. (Luke 24:1-7; Acts 2:32.)
>
> • He is now seated at the right hand of the 
>   Father in heaven. (Heb. 10:12.)
>
> • He is available to every person who will 
>   believe. (Rom. 10:13; John 1:12.)
>
> • He will come to live in you by the power 
>   and presence of the Holy Spirit living in 
>   your human spirit, once again making you 
>   alive to God. (Rom. 8:14-16.) (Note: You are encouraged to look up these Scriptures if you have a Bible. Let the Word of God convince you.)
>
> This is what it means to be born again. If you 
>   believe this, then you can:
>
> • Proceed by admitting you are a sinner in 
>   need of a Savior. (Rom. 3:23,24.)
>
> • Now confess your sins to God. (1 John 1:9.)
>
> • Have a repentant attitude—a willingness to 
>   turn from your sin and be willing to live a 
>   new life for God. (Acts 3:19)
>
> Let's Pray
>
> James 4:2 says you have not because you ask 
>   not. Ask Jesus into your heart; ask Him to forgive 
>   your sins. He will forgive you, and He will come 
>   to live in your spirit. Your spirit will come alive to 
>   God. Here is a sample prayer you may pray. 
>   However, I encourage you to pour your heart out 
>   to God in your own way.
>
> Father God, I believe Jesus Christ is Your 
>   Son, the Savior of the world. I believe He died on 
>   the cross for me, and He bore all of my sins. He 
>   went to hell and triumphed over death and the 
>   grave. I believe Jesus was resurrected from the 
>   dead and is now seated at Your right hand. I need 
>   You, Jesus. Forgive my sins, save me, come to live 
>   inside of me. I want to be born again.
>
> If you believe these truths and have followed 
>   the guidelines:
>
> Congratulations,
>
> you are born again!

Comment: @bruisedreed http://www.docstoc.com/docs/167813984/The-Most-Important-Decision-Youll-Ever-Make-by-Joyce-Meyerpdf but i dont know if it is legal

Comment: Some time after posting this question, I found [this video in which Joyce Meyer clearly mentions salvation by faith alone](http://youtu.be/r35d2XHRwvo) and even explicitly mentions [Ephesians 2:8-9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians+2%3A8-9&version=AMP) from my question. Hence, I am accepting this answer.

Comment: @Wikis Ok, thanks for the link.  She is also quite explicit at points in this message as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPhsu-w1H8Y

Comment: **No.** Just because she uses a few words related to this topic occasionally does not justify this answer. As [my answer postulates](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/27664/30) she does not mean the same thing when she uses the words as might be expected and her other teaching regularly contradicts these few examples. Anybody can parrot a few word following a formula to try to check off a box that evangelicals expect to hear, but that doesn't mean the message they actually preach is orthodox.

Answer (score 6):

> Does she preach the basic Christian message of salvation by faith in Jesus alone.

**No.**

Allow me to explain.

Another answer has postulated "yes", and there is a sense in which there are words she uses that can be construed that way. The trouble is most of them can also be construed another way. It is therefore necessary to look at the broader context of her teachings in order to determine how well they align with a "salvation by faith in Christ alone" Gospel.

This is a tricky issue because she mixes and matches a lot of content. Taken in isolation some, indeed many, points of her doctrine may seem in agreement with mainstream Christian teaching. It isn't until you put all the pieces together that you see the pieces fit in a different puzzle.

### Definition of terms and outline of scope

In order to treat an open-ended question like this on this site, I think it is necessary to identify who holds what views and who, exactly, has issues with what. For the purposes of the scope of this site, anyone self-professing to be Christian is on topic. Baring any further scoping (which your question is a bit thin on) I will be working under the assumption that you are questioning from a generic mainstream Protestant perspective.

Since it seems self evident that this question isn't directed at Catholicism or Orthodoxy and the (dubious) tag [biblical-basis](/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) tends to be the focus of Protestants, I'll be tackling this from that direction.

Broadly I find the following conflicts between Joyce's teaching on salvation and "salvation by faith".

1. She defines the concepts of faith and works differently.
2. She defines salvation differently.
3. It isn't her main message.

### Statement of faith

If you examine the [statement of faith](http://www.joycemeyer.org/content/Downloads/faith.pdf) from her website, there isn't much there to cause alarm. Most of it could pass for most any non-denominational or even Baptist. There are a couple of items that put it in a more Pentecostal camp, maybe most similar to AOG.

The trouble is the statements there are not consistent with what she teaches. For example point 1:

> The Bible is the infallible Word of God, inspired by the Holy Spirit, and contains every answer to man's problems.

Sounds good. The trouble is she doesn't actually hold to the sufficiency of Scripture doctrine held by mainstream Protestants. Instead she believes in continued special revelation. She teaches that some things Christians should know are not spelled out in the Bible.

> The Bible can’t even find any way to explain this. Not really that is why you have got to get it by revelation. There are no words to explain what I am telling you. I have got to just trust God that he is putting it into your spirit like he put it Into mine. — Joyce Meyer ([audio clip](http://storage.carm.org/audio/joycemeyer/joyce-meyer-revelation-knowledge.mp3))

In other words, her statement of faith is not an accurate guide to her teachings. Ergo when it comes to the part relevant to your question, we must examine whether the statement is actually reflected in her teachings.

> Man is created in the image of God but separated from God by sin. Without Jesus we cannot have a relationship with God.
>
> We can have a personal relationship with God through salvation, God's free gift to man. It is not a result of what we do, but it is only available through God's unearned favor. By admitting we have sinned and believing in the death, burial and resurrection of Christ, and accepting Him as Lord, we can spend eternity with God.

Alright so we have some stuff about Jesus, sin, salvation, personal relationship, etc. Fair enough.<sup>1</sup> Lets see how they play out.

#### Soundly Biblical?

Your question made this observation:

> I only saw one talk and it was soundly Biblical.

This analysis <strike>would be</strike> is widely disputed by mainstream Protestants. See for example [CARM's analysis](http://carm.org/joyce-meyer).

So lets break down to where the dispute lines fall:

- Starting easy, cults such as LDS and JW are different enough on core issues that no comparability is either implied or assumed.
- The structure of Catholic, Orthodox, and even Anglican churches differs enough from her independent organization of one that there isn't much question that they don't match up.
- Mainstream Protestants with which she is most often assumed to be associated (due in main part to her self-identification af 'simply Christian' have repeatedly disavowed her (some of the reasons for such are will be covered below).
- Doctrinally, there are some notably similarities with the Seventh Day Adventist Church. Her view of continued revelation is not that different from the role Ellen White plays in the SDAC. Her views on the relationship between salvation and sanctification are also similar. Notably different would be their views on hell where Joyce is fairly traditional and the SDAC is decidedly Annihilationist.

So who does she agree with? The theological school of thought with which she is *most properly identified with* is:

- Word of Faith

It is important to note that when I say "properly identified", I am referring to general theological constructs. She is not officially part of any movement or denomination. Her [FAQ](http://www.joycemeyer.org/AboutUs/FAQ.aspx), for example, skirts the issue a bit by agreeing with the general teachings while noting awareness of a common point of criticism.

> #### 13. Is Joyce Meyer Ministries a "word of faith" ministry?
>
> Joyce Meyer Ministries believes in the Word of God. Joyce teaches that God has made promises to us in His Word and as believers, we should trust His promises. However, it can be damaging when people place their faith in faith alone instead of placing their faith in God. Misappropriation of God’s promises solely for personal gain is not scripturally supported.

While most adherents don't use this terminology, Joyce is firmly in the realm of what mainstream Protestants would call 'Prosperity Gospel' or 'Health and Wealth'. Note what [Wikipeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyce_Meyer#See_also) gives for references. This distinctive is even openly claimed in her [FAQ](http://www.joycemeyer.org/AboutUs/FAQ.aspx), albeit with the same caveat as for Word of Faith, noting a weakness of the movement.

> #### 14. Does Joyce Meyer Ministries teach a "prosperity gospel"?
>
> Joyce Meyer Ministries believes that God desires to bless His people. Joyce teaches that God’s blessings and prosperity apply to the spiritual, emotional, physical and financial areas of life. These blessings and prosperity are then to be used to bless others. A "prosperity gospel" that solely equates blessing with financial gain is out of balance and could damage a person’s walk with God.

In any case the overwhelming majority of her teaching falls squarely in this camp, and her choice of associations brings that tie even closer. See appearances with T.D. Jakes (former Oneness Pentecostal, + Word of Faith), her citations of Benny Henn (on the short list of top Prosperity Gospel proponents) on humans being 'little gods', sinlessness, etc., etc.

If you consider Prosperity / Health & Wealth teachings to be "soundly Biblical", the following may or may not be points of concern for you, but they are certainly causes for concern for mainstream Protestants of many different denominations.

### So does she teach salvation by faith?

In addition to my previous knowledge and studies, in preparing for this answer, I reviewed about 3.5 hours of Joyce's teaching: 2 long conference segments and a few shorter messages (but still in whole segments so I'm sure I'm not just working with somebody else's cherry-picking. There are a couple of things to not from such a sampling.

1. While "faith" is often mentioned in her teachings including in the context of salvation, the fact that salvation if by faith alone is never stressed in the way that the Protestant doctrine of *sola fide* would have it be.

   Works are never mentioned as a means to salvation, but they are constantly mentioned as a means to everything else. Her teaching is riddled with stories, often of her own experiences. The vast majority of these follow a pattern of "struggle with x, then finally I did y" or "make x mistake, then I realized y and did z". From a pragmatic standpoint a lot of preachers messages will include talk like this from time to time, but Joyce's preaching is exceptional for the pervasive use of the "I did" pattern. It is classic self-help coaching. God doing things and changing people is hardly given mention expect in *response* to something that men do first. All his action / blessing / etc is done as a result to somebody else's actions.

   Here is a direct quote I heard in multiple sessions speaking to that theology:

   > If we do things God's way God will give us double for our trouble. — Joyce Meyer

   The scenario is constantly 'we do x, then and only then does God step up to do y'.
2. Her concept of "salvation" is at variance with Protestantism on the issue of sanctification.

   In Protestant theology, we are saved from sin and justified before God once and for all by means of Christ's propitiatory death. Of the various [pieces that make up salvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordo_salutis), justification happens once and for all but the process of our sanctification as believers is underway but not finished yet. Joyce completely disagrees with this and **believes that as a result of her salvation she does not sin**.

   > I am not poor. I am not miserable and I am not a sinner. That is a lie from the pit of hell. That is what I were and if I still was then Jesus died in vain. I'm going to tell you something folks. I didn't stop sinning until I finally got it through my thick head I wasn't a sinner anymore. And the religious world thinks that's heresy and they want to hang you for it. But the Bible says that I am righteous and I can't be righteous and be a sinner at the same time. — Joyce Meyer ([youtube source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dmHJdM63hk))

   If the context of the Protestant doctrine of salvation my faith alone, the 'not by works' clause is a necessary clarification because we believe we are still sinners and, even in our 'saved' state we continue to sin. Hopefully we are learning to recognize sin, repent from sin, etc. We are in the process of putting sin to death, but it hasn't been completely purged from us yet. That's the ongoing process of sanctification that *will not be completed until we are taken up to glory in Chris's presence*. Ergo if our salvation depended on our works we would fail. We continue to sin and grieve God even as his adopted children.

   In contrast the clause 'not by works' is basically meaningless for Joyce because she believes she is no longer a sinner and does not sin. So whether her salvation depended on works or not is no longer a meaningful distinction. She is correct in identifying that most of the religious world (by which I assume she means "Christian" world) believes this to be heresy.

   Somebody who believes they can be / are currently sinless in our earthly pre-glorification state cannot be said to preach "salvation by faith" in the same way other Protestants do because she means something different when she says 'salvation'. To her credit she does teach a fairly orthodox view of hell and that we are saved from it by Jesus having gone there in our place<sup>2</sup>, but again very little airtime is given to the work of Christ in her teachings, most of it is human focused, self-help-ism.
3. In nearly well over 3 hours of whole segments, the amount of time she spent making any remarks on salvation at all was less than 5 minutes sum-total.

   Can it properly be said that someone who does not devote *any* attention to a subject at "preaches" it per your question? I think not. She does not "preach" salvation an all. Her attention is solely on other matters.

   Given that her professed ministry focus is to believers, is this appropriate?

   - Reading the apostolic letters to the NT churches addressed to believers, the amount of focus placed on salvation and how it works is *much* higher. I havn't done the statistics but my gut level instinct based on reading and preaching the NT is that it's closer to 1/3 that 1/50.
   - Most of Protestantism places a high value on the fundamentals of salvation in Christ, giving it regular airtime even to audiences that are assumed to be mostly Christian.

### Conclusion

The specifics of your question boil down to this:

- Does Joyce Meyer use a lot of words and phrases that sound familiar to evangelical ears? **Sure.**
- When she uses there words, does she mean the same thing by them as is meant by most Protestants? **Clearly not.**

So can it be claimed that she "preaches salvation by faith" when a) none of the other pieces of her doctrine fit the puzzle that *sola fide* came from and b) most of what she preaches is something else entirely that is at fundamental variance with what *sola fide* brings with it doctrinally? **No.** She does not preach a gospel and a salvation that is consistent with "And this is not of yourselves, but it is the gift of God;".

---

End note regarding your comment about translations:

> Quoting from the Amplified version which seems to be her preference.

Interesting that you should note this. There is nothing inherently wrong with the Amplified version and it certainly serves a purpose. However, extensive reliance on it in teaching is a signal that there may be hermeneutical problems with the message. It can be useful in identifying the inherent difficulty of mapping Biblical languages to English and for getting your head around the possible senses of a text, but it does not help you settle on which sense(s) were intended and or guide correct interpretation. If not combined with other good hermeneutical practices, it leaves the text open to possibly saying much more (or quite different) things than it should rightly interpreted to say.

This tends to make it a favorite by teachers who don't actually have another hermeneutical leg to stand on. The Amplified translation, while a good tool used properly, in this scenario becomes a convenient spring-board for making a passage say whatever a speaker wants it to say. In the case of Joyce Meyer, she makes no bones about the fact that she does not believe the words of Scripture alone are sufficient to understand God's message and that she believes she has a special anointing to do explain things beyond the words of Scripture.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually not fine, my Reformed inclinations also want to point out the issue with "by admitting" being made causative rather that being a result of God's work in changing hearts, but for the body of my answer I am trying to stick to a generic Evangelical viewpoint.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Most Protestants would again disagree with her on the exact mechanics of this as they believe the wrath of God was poured out on Christ while on the cross, not later in hell. Whether or not (and why) Christ spent time in hell is not universally agreed on, but that the thing he did in our place was completed on the cross is generally agreed on, which Meyers rejects.</sub>

Comment: @Caleb your quote "The Bible can’t even find any way to explain this. Not really that is why you have got to get it by revelation. There are no words to explain what I am telling you. I have got to just trust God that he is putting it into your spirit like he put it into mine. — Joyce Meyer" is not in her statement of faith - can you please provide a reference for it.

Comment: @bruisedreed I believe that quote came from a conference recording. I recall seeing that bit in context off the DVD at some point but have been unable to locate a full source online. The soud-byte excerpt is available online many places. If anyone finds a fuller excerpt please feel free to link it here!

Comment: @bruisedreed I've seen the quote second hand on CARM.org [They have an Mp3](http://storage.carm.org/audio/joycemeyer/joyce-meyer-revelation-knowledge.mp3). If that's her voice she certainly said it. The lack of context is concerning, however. CARM seems pretty reasonable. They would probably know and willingly tell you exactly where it came from.

Comment: This answer spends way too much time answering questions the OP didn't ask, such that those wanting an actual answer to the question asked have to wade through a lot of tangential material. Honestly, I didn't bother to read it all.

Comment: @Lee Oh come on. The actual answer is one bolded word at the top. Those that don't care to dig deeper than surface similarities will go with the contradictory answer anyway, defending this answer takes a bit of reasoning. I don't think my statement of purpose, outline of reasoning, definition of terms, supporting evidence, and conclusion are unreasonably long or hard to follow, nor are they tangential. The topics are pretty foundational to the doctrine being challenged.

Comment: I have now read the entire answer. And I now think even more strongly that most of it is irrelevant to the OP's actual question. Even if JM is wrong about all of the other topics you say she's wrong about, that still doesn't mean she doesn't teach faith alone. And even if she doesn't put big emphasis on it, that *still* doesn't mean she doesn't teach faith alone. Paul devoted most of his letters to teachings about how to live. Does that mean Paul is wrong? This answer simply *doesn't* answer the OP's question.

Comment: Additionally, saying that she doesn't teach faith alone the way evangelical or mainstream Protestants do *still* doesn't mean that she doesn't teach faith alone. It just means that if she *does* teach faith alone, she doesn't do so in the same way as her more mainstream Protestant brothers and sisters. This answer's basic argument seems to be, "She's wrong about all these other things, so she must be wrong and not teach faith alone." The answer provides no documentary support whatsoever for its initial answer of **No.**

Comment: And re: the final note on using the Amplified Bible, attacking JM's skill as a biblical exegete *also* has no bearing on whether or not she teaches faith alone.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Your criticism really only makes sense if I was trying to answer a truth question. I'm not. I'm only answering this in the context of the classical Protestant definition of a doctrine. I outline the differences between Joyce's teaching and the classic usage of the doctrine to show how they are different. I think your disagreement with the doctrine in question is showing through a bit more than you think, I'm bracketing my entire answer and defending it based on that scope. You don't have to agree with these views but they are _representative of the scope implied by the question_.

Comment: My views have nothing to do with it. I don't even know who Joyce Meyer is, nor do I care whether or not she preaches salvation by faith alone. And the OP's recent rejection of my attempt to scope the question to Protestantism shows that your answering it "in the context of the classical Protestant definition of a doctrine" is answering a question that the OP is not asking. The OP is, rather, asking if JM preaches "the basic Christian message" of "salvation by faith in Jesus alone (ie not works)." I.e., does JM preach faith alone in *any* form. Your answer doesn't address the question asked.

Comment: @Caleb - Thanks, it's helpful.