# What is the gist of CARM's criticism of Joyce Meyer?

Tags: protestantism, heresy, comparative-christianity, carm

[Joyce Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyce_Meyer) was accused of false teaching by [CARM](http://carm.org/). I can find no response from Joyce Meyer ministries as to misrepresentation, and CARM refer to some poor audio tapes and her book written in 1993. I'm confused, because she appears to me to be on point, but is accused of heresy and other non biblical teachings.

Comment: Joyce Meyer is heavily into what is known as the "Word of Faith" movement, the teachings of which are quite different from mainstream Christian teachings which CARM defends. I [answered a similar question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/27664/30) with some information that might be helpful to you in sorting out the positions.

Comment: @Caleb That's excellent thank you so much I understand your answer you have broken it down for me, it is so hard when someone appears to be Christian yet differs on major doctrinal issues.   I had no idea and had not picked up on these things when listening to her.  I also queried CARM's references to poor audio recordings on you tube. I now understand the differences, and this word-faith teaching which I have never come across before.  I really appreciate your time, thank you and God Bless

Comment: You might like to read [this blog post](http://churchismessy.com/2013/08/05/why-i-called-out-joel-osteen-and-joyce-meyer/). It seems to have decent audio recordings.

Comment: @Caleb CARM is not "mainstream," but "conservative" or "fundamentalist" within the overall spectrum of Christianity. It adheres to a form of Protestantism that takes the Bible very literally, unlike the mainstream, or mainline, Protestant churches.

Answer (score 12):

[CARM has said a few things about Joyce Meyer](https://carm.org/joyce-meyer) and has called some of her teachings heresy.

> [CARM was] glad to see an affirmation [in Meyer's teachings] of the Trinity, that man is a sinner, that without Jesus we can have no relationship with God, that salvation is a free gift, and eternal hell of conscious damnation.

Some things Meyer has said that CARM has labeled as misguided or heresy are:

- "Jesus stopped being the Son of God on the cross." CARM calls this heresy and dangerous and urges Meyer to repent.
- "Jesus was the first person to be born again." CARM calls this "a serious error since it implies that Jesus needed to be changed"
- "Jesus paid for our sins in Hell." CARM says Jesus paid for our sins on the cross.
- "Jesus went to Hell in our place and suffered and was tormented." CARM says there is no reason to believe that Jesus suffered in Hell to finish atonement for the sins of the World.
- "If you don't believe that Jesus went to Hell you cannot be saved." CARM calls this heresy.
- Joyce Meyer describes her Christ given righteousness in a way that CARM finds unbiblical and motivated by pride.
- "Demons literally stood on Jesus in Hell and laughed." CARM calls this completely made up and part of the same heresy that Jesus was tormented in Hell.
- Meyer claims to have a gift of revelation from God, but CARM argues that must be impossible because some of her teachings stand in contrast to what the Bible says.

It seems that most of CARM's objections relate to Meyer's teaching that the cross was not sufficient and required Jesus to be tormented in Hell too.

Additionally, CARM takes objection that Meyer has taken the proper role of a preacher which CARM believes is a position that should only be held by men.

Since first approaching her in 2011, CARM claims that Joyce Meyer has not responded to their inquiries or accusations.

---

Sources:

- [*Joyce Meyer* by Matt Slick - CARM.org](https://carm.org/joyce-meyer)
- [*Did Jesus die spiritually?* by Matt Slick - CARM.org](https://carm.org/did-jesus-die-spiritually)

Comment: The one thing this answer could use is specific references to the sources of alleged heresy or at least provide some sort of summary as to the sources where Meyer taught these things. A part of the question regards the legitimacy of the allegations and (perhaps) whether or not she still teaches (or has not since recanted) these things.

Comment: @mojo I believe you are right. If I find some time, I'll do some digging. I do know that CARM has some sound bytes, but they are incomplete (i.e. lacking context).

Comment: I have been unable to find any recants.  Which also caused me concern, I found references to all but one of CARM's links, poor audio tapes that didn't sound like Joyce, however when I followed Calebs link to his previous answer (similar question) I found sufficient and clear answers to the Word of faith movement and heresy allegations.  I appreciate it very much, I have also sent a personal query to Joyce Meyer Ministries asking if there is any response that I could read and understand where she stands.  I guess I will be able to deduct my own opinion from their response or lack of thereof....

Comment: @LeanneWarrener Any response?